# Chinese characters and the onkeypress event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Using Internet Explorer on Windows I have an `onkeypress` event detecting text entered into a text box.  However when entering Chinese characters this event doesn't fire.  Has anyone encountered this or have suggestions on working around this?

Comment: are you using a program that inserts the chinesse characters programmatically and not a standard keyboard?

Comment: The way I'm doing it is with a Latin keyboard to enter Chinese characters using Windows' Chinese locale settings (type the sounds and you get the characters prompted for selection).

Comment: make sure it has utf-8 encoding

Comment: To answer the why: it definitely seems like the Windows system for entering Chinese characters using a Latin keyboard intercepts the keypresses and doesn't simulate a keypress to enter the resulting character.  As a result this breaks onkeypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/E4Bdz/2/), it seems the `keydown` event does not fire as one might expect.  I would use the `keyup` event (though, you'll still get partially entered characters).

From my experiment, I got:

- An event for "ni" instead of 你
- An event '你ha'
- An event for 你哈 (since the alert killed my input to complete 'hao')

Basically, Windows and IE are not playing nicely with character input.  I would suggest using the `change` event if it's possible in your framework.

Answer (score 5):

Google Suggest (autocomplete) polls the input for changes as the events are completely unreliable for Unicode.  Browsers used to support mid-IME input events which was very nice for Japanese, but support quickly broke or was dropped.

Last time I check was 2006 though, so retesting is required.  Here are my previous notes:

http://web.archive.org/web/20060220125639/http://fnjordy.cus.org.uk/auto/

Including non-resolved bug in Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286842

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the keyboard settings, writing a single Chinese character usually requires typing several keys. For example, 豈 can be written using a 4-key sequence (山一口廿), as you can see here: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B1%88

You need to use an onchange event in this case (and also for Korean and Japanese!)